# Gradle Profiling Report: Task 'Did No Work'

Tags: gradle, report, profile

Having challenges understanding Gradle *profile* reports that have an executed task with a result of "Did no work."

If I executed the *build* task successfully, after the *clean* task, why would the profile report say that the build task "Did no work?"  It obviously executed the other tasks along the Java plug-in task list hierarchy, i.e. build dependsOn compile, etc.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

The Gradle documentation simply states that the result will be reflected as tasks that were not skipped but did no work.  Does this mean that the ***build* task literaly does no work** and just calls and/or dependsOn other sub-tasks in the Java plugin?

Answer (score 0):

there are two scenarios I can think of why a task is considered up-to-date even on a clean build:

1. The task has no own actions declared (as you already figured out. E.g the `build` task, which is just what we call `lifecycle task` that gathers task dependencies)
2. the task has no inputs at all to process. (e.g. you see the `processResources` task is marked as up-to-date because you have no resources declared in your project)

Comment: My question revolved around the profile report stating a task "Did no work." I'm not confused about the "up-to-date" task status, a major feature of the Gradle build toolkit.